# LinkedIN API in Asp.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, linkedin-api

Is there any way to implement LinkedIN API by using C#,VB.NET.
We need to call profile , companies ,Jobs etc API of linked in using mentioned technologies.

Comment: there is already a ready made client for this. checkout my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16959164/1867929).

Answer (score 6):

Linkedin have a REST based API - http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/DOC-1258

You can create a HttpWebRequest, pointed at a REST endoint, and parse the response however you wish.

```
// Create the web request  
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections/") as HttpWebRequest;  

// Get response  
using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)  
{  
    // Get the response stream  
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());  

    // Console application output  
    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());  
}
```

Comment: Hi,Any implementation in C#,VB.NET for this purpose like see user profile , user connections , companies info etc

Comment: There are no pre-built C# wrappers that I know of. However, you can use the method above to 'roll your own' hopefully without too much difficulty.

Comment: Assuming you can get the OAuth tokens, calculate the OAuth signature, and add it to the request. That makes it slightly more difficult to roll your own.

Answer (score 4):

In my point of view it is better to use some existed c# wrapper. Look at [LinkedIn Developer Toolkit](https://github.com/deeja/LinkedInDeveloperToolkit).

Comment: +1 for the project link, but I don't follow your argument - more adaptable?

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on the [LinkedInNET lib on github](https://github.com/SparkleNetworks/LinkedInNET). The API coverage is not full but it's growing.

There is a NuGet package btw.

```
PM> Install-Package Sparkle.LinkedInNET
```

Answer (score 0):

[Spring.NET Social (LinkedIn extension)](http://www.springframework.net/social-linkedin/) is so far, the best LinkedIn API Client I've used. It's an extension of [Spring.NET Social](http://www.springframework.net/social/index.html).

Although you can always consume the LinkedIn REST API using your own consumer/other 3rd party REST API consumer such as [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/), I would say that using Spring.NET REST combined with this LinkedIn API Client is a breeze.